# Including code- and Log.d listing

Tags: support

For a question I want to include a substantial part of the code and the Log.d output. What is the best way to handle this?

Would a link to Google's-drive work?

Comment: Break it down, try to isolate the problem to it's smallest part and post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)(you will probably solve it when you will try to do it and then you won't need to post at all!).

Comment: Spend an hour or two debugging the issue and boiling it down to the essential code which makes the error reproducible. Don’t include any more code or log data than is absolutely necessary to exhibit and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good on you for asking here first! Downvotes here a) don't affect your reputation and b) could be interpreted along the lines of "you shouldn't do it like that", not "this is a bad question".

Answer (score 12):

**Any time you want to or think you need to include a substantial amount of code or logging, you should stop and reconsider.**

It's important to give us as much detail as necessary to help answer your question, and nothing more.  Adding too much detail or introducing too much complexity in your question isn't encouraged.